# How to find average walking time per day

Tags: problem-solving, unit-of-measure

I have calculated that the total walking time for a person is 2990702 minutes in 801 days. I want to know his average walking time per day in minutes. I dont know if I need to convert minutes into hours or minutes into days or something else. Please help me with the correct conversion, formula and answer to tele my results. Thanks

Comment: I don't think this is functional analysis or mathematical physics

Answer (score 1):

If someone walks for $2990702$ minutes in $801$ days, said person walks $2990702\div801 = 3733.71036$ minutes per day on average.

Answer (score 0):

Because minutes and days are both units of time, you can get a dimensionless result.  As elDino said, you can just divide to get $3733.71036$ minutes per day.  There are $60 \cdot 24=1440$ minutes in a day, so you could rewrite this as $3733.71036$ mintues per $1440$ minutes, which says he is walking about $2.6$ times as many minutes as there are.  If the walking time were $299070$, you would say he is walking $0.26$ of the time